# Reading data from hive and displaying in HTML

Tags: html, shell, hive

I am trying to read data from hive table via shell script and sending the returned result from hive query, in an email using html. However, often there is a random space introduced in the email generated by the shell script.

Below is the code snippet from my shell script:

```
function sendAlertEmail {

res=`hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=false;set hive.execution.engine=tez;select rule_id,kpi_area,rule_desc,cast(current_result as decimal(5,2)),current_run_ts,cast(previous_result as decimal(5,2)),previous_run_timestamp,email_id from email_alert;' | tr -s '\t' '|'`

size=${#res[@]}

table_body=
IFS=$'\n'
for lines in $res
do
  IFS='|' read -r -a array <<< "$lines"
  table_body="$table_body <tr><td>${array[0]}</td><td>${array[1]}</td><td>${array[2]}</td><td>${array[3]}</td><td>${array[4]}</td><td>${array[5]}</td><td>${a
rray[6]}</td></tr>"
  email_id=${array[7]}
done

if [[ -z $table_body ]];then
  echo "No records found"
  exit 0
fi

table_body="<table border='1'><thead><th>RULE_ID</th><th>KPI_AREA</th><th>RULE_DESC</th><th>CURRENT_RESULT</th><th>CURRENT_RUN_TIMESTAMP</th><th>PREVIOUS_RESULT
</th><th>PREVIOUS_RUN_TIMESTAMP</th></thead><tbodY>$table_body</tbody></table>"
table_body="$table_body <br/><i>This is an automated email. Do not reply to this email"
(cat <<END; echo -e $table_body) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
Subject: Alert Email
From:
To: $email_id
Content-Type: text/html;
X-Priority: 1

END
}
```

Attached is the screenshot of the email received with random space.

[image: Email Screenshot]

Note the space in fifth record in the word "Wireless". This space is random and does not appear at the same place every time I call the email function.

Can anyone please let me know what could be causing the random space being introduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing HTML as a single long line.

Outlook has some issue with line length and it inserts a new line after a certain amount of characters. This new line causes such gaps in words. Sometimes it is inserted not inside the word and it is being displayed good then.

The solution is to insert line brakes between HTML tags. 
Like this:

```
table_body="<table border='1'>
<thead><th>RULE_ID</th>
<th>KPI_AREA</th>
<th>RULE_DESC</th>
<th>CURRENT_RESULT</th>
<th>CURRENT_RUN_TIMESTAMP</th>
<th>PREVIOUS_RESULT
</th><th>PREVIOUS_RUN_TIMESTAMP</th>
</thead>
<tbodY>$table_body</tbody>
</table>"
```

And the same for the first `for lines` loop.

And do not forget to check that all your code works correctly with variables containing line breaks. For example this  `echo -e $table_body` the variable should be quoted:  `echo -e "$table_body"`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have made the suggested changes and had a run. However now instead of the random space, the HTML tag </td> appears, not every time but randomly.

Comment: :) @IshanSharma Sorry, I did not test it of course. Extra line breaks can break HTML in email also, so you better test it carefully. But what I know for sure - outlook does not like too long lines

Comment: @IshanSharma please publish your findings. It will be very useful for everyone doing the same. This task is not so rare

Comment: Posting my findings: 1. Incorporated the suggestions by @leftjoin 2. The hive table being queried above had row format serde as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'. I dropped the table and recreated it as simple text file. The random space has not come since these changes